# BeautifulSoup Python how do i return all the values from my for loop as list in my function

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have have a function with a for loop.  It iterates over a table of columns and prints out each value to the console.
I would like to put a return statement at the end of the function so when i call the function I can have all the values returned.
I think I would need to return it as a list.

My function is:

```
def extract_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"C:\temp\selenium_report\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#result_table")
    headers = [td.text for td in table.select_one("#header_row").find_all("td")[1:-1]]
    print(" ".join(headers))
    for row in table.select("tr.passClass"):
        print(" ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td")[1:-1]]))
```

How do i put the return at the end and return each value from the for loop?

The for loop prints out the following:

```
Count Pass Fail Error
75 75 0 0
```

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's stopping you from just creating an empty list and appending to it?

```
def extract_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"C:\temp\selenium_report\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#result_table")

    #Create list here...
    results = []

    headers = [td.text for td in table.select_one("#header_row").find_all("td")[1:-1]]
    print(" ".join(headers))

    #Don't forget to append header (if you want)
    results.append(headers)

    for row in table.select("tr.passClass"):
        #Store row string in variable and append before printing
        row_str = " ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td")[1:-1]]))
        results.append(row_str)
        print(row_str)

    return results
```

Answer (score 1):

You can yield each string:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"C:\temp\selenium_report\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#result_table")
    headers = [td.text for td in table.select_one("#header_row").find_all("td")[1:-1]]
    yield (" ".join(headers))
    for row in table.select("tr.passClass"):
        yield " ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td")[1:-1]])
```

Then call `list(extract_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner())` or  iterate over the generator function:

```
for row in extract_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner():
   # use each row
```